# How to convert ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to String[][]?

Tags: java, arraylist

You can convert an `ArrayList<String>` to `String[]` using:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("one");
stringList.add("two");
String[] strings1 = Arrays.copyOf(stringList.toArray(), stringList.toArray().length, String[].class);
```

But how do you convert an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to `String[][]` ?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfStringLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: You answered your own questions at the same time you posted ?

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow gives you the option to submit an answer when you post a question. I spent some time searching and couldn't find anything so I've posted my method that works. But your free to submit any better solutions!

Comment: You answered in 4-5 seconds. I think you were trying to post some tutorial on conversion. I am not sure whether it is allowed or not. In any case, this sounded like question.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] strings2 = convertStringArrayList(listOfStringLists);
```

Convert `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to `String[][]` method:

```
private String[][] convertStringArrayList( ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfStringLists ) {
    String[][] stringGroups = new String[listOfStringLists.size()][];
    for ( int i=0; i< listOfStringLists.size(); i++ ) {
        ArrayList<String> stringArray = listOfStringLists.get(i);
        String[] stringsChildren = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray.toArray(), stringArray.toArray().length, String[].class);
        stringGroups[i] = stringsChildren;
    }
    return stringGroups;
}
```